# Reporting progress from ViewModel method executed in a Task

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, progress

i'm trying to report progress from ViewModel (MVVM Light) methods that are executed in a task. The ProgressViewModel contains a ProgressModel property that provides properties to describe the current state. Those properties are bound to an Xceed `BusyIndicator`. So far, so good. But its not working as expected. The `ProgressModel.IsRunning` is bound to `BusyIndiciator.IsBusy` and toggles the visibility - that works. `ProgressModel.Description` and `ProgressModel.Percentage` are bound to a `TextBlock.Text`/`ProgressBar.Value` - but they are not updated...

So... since `IsRunning` works, whats wrong with `Description` and `Progress`...?

```
// Model
public sealed class ProgressModel: ObservableObject
{
    private string m_description;
    private float m_percentage;
    private bool m_running;

    public string Description
    {
        get { return m_description; }
        set { Set(ref m_description, value); }
    }
    public float Percentage
    {
        get { return m_percentage; }
        set { Set(ref m_percentage, value); }
    }
    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return m_running; }
        set{Set(ref m_running, value);}
    }

    public void Initiate()
    {
        Description = string.Empty;
        Percentage = 0;
        IsRunning = true;
    }
}
// Command
private void DownloadWatch()
{
    DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        Progress.Initiate();
    });
    using (var watch = new PolarWatch())
    {
        watch.Connect();
        for (var i = 0; i < watch.Sessions.Count; i++)
        {
            DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Progress.Description = $"Writing session data for '{session.DateTime}'...";
            });
        }
    }
    DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        Progress.IsRunning = false;
    });
}
// View
<xctk:BusyIndicator Name="Busy" IsBusy="{Binding Progress.IsRunning}">
    <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="150">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Progress.Description}"/>
                <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Value="{Binding Progress.Percentage}" Height="14" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
    <xctk:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
```

Comment: this would normally be done by passing in a IProgress<T> to your task see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MikeT: in WPF, it's normally done as shown above, just by setting a progress value bound to a WPF control. WPF handles the cross-thread update implicitly in that scenario, and there's no need for `Progress<T>`. Indeed, the code above has `Invoke()` calls that aren't even necessary; the binding would work even without those.

Comment: Have you tried `set { Set( nameof(Percentage),ref m_percentage, value); }` ?

Comment: Ah, wait a sec ... are you sure they are _not_ set? Is it just a timing issue? In the function you do watch.Connect and then you iterate sessions and right after you disable the BusyIndicator. Could it be that this is executed so fast you just don't see it?

Comment: Maybe try and add a `Progress.Description="Connecting ..."` right before you do watch.Connect and see if it is shown in the indicator.

Comment: @Fildor Neither text or progress is shown. The window shows the busy indicator and then the form is frozen for about 15 seconds, then the visibility of the busy indicator is toggled. In debugger description/percentage of the Progress property is modified, but the UI is not updated...

Comment: Oh, ... are you calling `DownloadWatch()` on the UI thread?

Comment: No, its called from a `RelayCommand` like this `async () => await Task.Run(() => DownloadWatch())` - thats not the exact code since i'm at home now... i'll swap this for an real async ICommand later, its just for testing.

Comment: A down-vote one week after my question has been solved...? Would you like to explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the root element in the `ItemTemplate` is not the same as the `DataContext` of the control itself. Try this:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding DataContext.Progress.Description, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=xctk:BusyIndicator}}"/>
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Value="{Binding DataContext.Progress.Percentage,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=xctk:BusyIndicator}}" Height="14" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
```

Or set the `DataContext` of the `Grid`:

```
<Grid Width="150" DataContext="{Binding DataContext.Progress, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=xctk:BusyIndicator}}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Value="{Binding Percentage}" Height="14" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sounds good. I'll try this at monday. Could you give me a short explanation why the `DataContext` isn't the same? i would expect that if I did not specifiy another `DataContext` the root/parent `DataContext` would be used...

Comment: No, the DataContext of the ContentTemplate of a ContentControl is the Content of the ContentControl.

Comment: Thats some nice wording. Have to read it twice until i got it. Thx :)